# add auto increment to exists table in pgsql (using adminer)

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I have a table foo with PRIMARY key is 'id' (UUID) and now it have 300k records.
Now I need to add new field with AUTO-INCREMENT and start from 1000001

Answer (score 0):

**1. Step 1:**  add new SEQUENCE start from your number

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_quick_code_seq START 10000001;
```

**2. Step 2:**

1. add new fields: 'quick_code' with default value is nextval('foo_quick_code_seq '),
2. remember don't check AI(auto-increment) radio button.
   [image]

**3. Step 3: waiting for running & check result**
[image]

**for quick SQL query**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_quick_code_seq START 10000001;
ALTER TABLE "foo"
ADD "short_code" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('foo_quick_code_seq');
```

Comment: Note that in general `identity` columns are recommended for this in modern Postgres versions.